# add and remove boxes using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, textbox, addition, removechild

I have two text boxes and two buttons named add and remove. The requirement is to add more boxes along with the current boxes. i somehow managed to add boxes but the requirement of removing the boxes is not working. Please help to why this code is not working and if possible suggest a working solution.

```js
function addFunction(){
  var element = document.createElement("input");
  var parent = document.getElementById("form1");
  parent.appendChild(element);
}

function removeFunction(){
  var child = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
  var parent = document.getElementById("form1");

  for (var i = 0; i > child.length; i++) {
    parent.removeChild(child[i]);
  };
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form id="form1" style="margin-left: 40%; margin-top: 100px;">
      <input type="text" id="one"><br><br><br>
      <input type="text" id="two"><br>
      <p id ="demo"> </p>
    </form>
    <button style="margin-left: 40%;" type="button" value="ADD" id="addButton" onclick="addFunction()">ADD</button>
    <button style="margin-left:50px;" type="button" value="REMOVE" id="removeButton" onclick="removeFunction()">REMOVE</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: you need to `clone` the `node` before appending the same https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode

Answer (score 1):

```
for (var i = 0; i <  child.length; i++) {
        parent.removeChild(child[i]);
    };
```

You have got wrong condition in your for loop. Your `i` is always 0 at start, and is lesser then length of array with node elements, so loop just can't start.
P.s. and you don't need `var i` before it

Answer (score 1):

Your for-Loop is wrong:

```
        for (var i = 0; i > child.length; i++) {
            parent.removeChild(child[i]);
        };
```

You need to change ">" to "<"

Answer (score 1):

Replace your > condition in the for loop with <. You want the for loop to be executed until it reach child.length.

Comment: yeah i did it but its saying that my up votes are recorded but it wont be shown publicly since i have less than 15 reputations..